# Changing Unit of Analysis from Employee to Employer Level

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an administrative dataset with employees receiving a wage subsidy, along with the employer_name for each observation. However, rather than analyzing data at the individual level; I would like to change my unit of analysis into the employer level.

Specifically, I would like to see employer_name A has 10 subsidized employees, employer_name B has 4 subsidized employees, etc.

I tried the following:

However, this simply arranges individual observations by employer_name.

```
employee_subsidy5 %>%
  group_by(employer_name)
```

Comment: add a `%>% summarise(count = n())` that should fix your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `summarise` function will solve your problem.

```
df <- employee_subsidy5 %>%
  group_by(employer_name) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

Comment: Is it possible to add another variable, monthly_wage, and show an average of this variable at the employer_name level, along with the number of employees?

For example, employer_name A has 10 employees and an average monthly_wage of 4500, employer_name B has 6 employees and an average monthly_wage of 6500.

Comment: Sure, simply add those in the `summarise()` function, i.e. `summarise(count = n(), TheMean = mean(monthly_wage))` This will take a mean of those employees in the employer_name level, for each employer

Comment: I am trying this code and I am not getting an error, but it's not producing the result I am looking for:

```
df %>%
  group_by(employee_subsidy5) %>% summarize(count = n(), average_wage_per_employer = mean(monthly_wage))
```

Comment: `df <- employee_subsidy5 %>%
  group_by(employer_name) %>%
  summarise(count = n(),
            average_wage_per_employer = sum(monthly_wage)/n())`